# Printing only most frequency uppercase letter, digits python

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, key

I had to open a text file and find frequency of characters then
by using dictionary, I managed to get dictionary with letters & frequency and digit & frequency.
The thing is I have to print only most frequency used upppercase letter with frequency and most frequency digit with frequency.
I tried every if statement but it seems to not work.

ex: dictionary = {l:1, b: 6, A:5, 2:1, 5:3}
it prints("Most used uppercase letter is: A and used 5 times.)

Comment: How does your code look so far?

Comment: It looks okay but I was more looking for if statement that will solve this problem.

Comment: @user2745401, Why do you want the solution that use `if`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [`max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
>>> d = {'l':1, 'b': 6, 'A':5, '2':1, '5':3}
>>> digit = max(filter(str.isdigit, d), key=d.get)
>>> digit, d[digit]
('5', 3)
>>> upper = max(filter(str.isupper, d), key=d.get)
>>> upper, d[upper]
('A', 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension or Generator expression is also useful.

```
>>> dic = {'l': 1, 'b': 6, 'A': 5, '2':1, 'B': 2, '5': 3}
>>> upper_words = ((word, frequency) for word, frequency in dic.iteritems() if word.isupper())
>>> more_frequently = lambda x1, x2: x2 if x2[1] > x1[1] else x1
>>> reduce(more_frequently, upper_words)
('A', 5)
```